# Device is showing in device manager but not in Android ADB Interface?

Tags: adb, tablet

Hi I am Having some problems while using adb on my computer.
I connected tab to my laptop with a usb cable.
And This is the device manager.

[image]
Here you see that my lenovo tab is connected but not connected in android device.
I typed adb devices in cmd and too it showed "List of devices attached" and nothing else.
Please reply as fast as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have the latest USB drivers for your device installed on your computer. Also make sure that USB Debugging is enabled. If the problem persists, you may try reinstalling the drivers. May I know if you are using adb as sideload to flash roms or other usage?

Comment: Isn't there any way to enable USB Debugging without going to settings. There there is a method by using TWRP but to install TWRP you will also need USB Debugging for ADB to work.